# Is it possible to modify the settings from an .frm file in the executable?

Tags: vb6, reverse-engineering

I have a compiled VB6 application without access to the source. Is it possible to modify certain settings made in the .frm file in the executable? In my case I want to change the color of a control.

I guess the general answer would be "no", but since it is possible with Delphi applications, because there the forms are stored as resources, I was hoping something similar is possible for VB6 applications.

I don't mind getting my hands dirty using a hex editor, but for that I must have at least an idea for what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the answer is "no".  None of these values are in obvious locations within the executable, such as resources, so you'll just have to spend tedious amounts of time with the hex editor.

Comment: If you could step it through a dissasemlber it *might* help track down the color value. If resources are managed in a wacky way however, it will throw you off coarse completely. The things we do to change the bg color from fuchsia...